# Access denied on Published Pages but not on Wordpress /wp-admin/

Tags: user-access

I have a website, where all of a sudden I'm getting "403 Forbidden" in the status for the request url, and Access denied in the HTML page.

This issue is happening only with the links of published pages. /wp-admin/ is fine and I could edit and publish the page. But when hitting the page link, I am getting Access denied.

Following is the environment details of my site.

- Shared hosting.
- Wordpress Framework version 5.4.2.

I am able to

- connect via ftp.
- access html files.

I tried

- disabling all plugins (including changing plugins folder name)
- .htaccess file is fine

Please let me know what permissions to check and where.

Comment: Can you see your web server error log to get more information? It's useful to paste the whole error from your error log. Has anything else changed on your hosting?

Comment: thank you @mozboz The issue was with file permissions. Once they are reset, issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

After talking to my hosting provider, many a times, the issue finally got resolved.

Solution: Fixing directory and file permissions.

I was told that:
All directories should have the permission 755. And, all files should have the permission 644.

Once, the hosting provider reset permissions of all the directories and files present in the folder to which the website is pointing to, the issue is resolved.